# GitHub link giving 404 error when copy pasting the exact same link to repo/directory

Tags: github, http-status-code-404

I am trying to share the link of the directory under my public repository in GitHub, but when I copy & paste the exact same link I got from my browser it gives me 404 error. (e.g. [https://github.com/jjeongin/intro‐to‐IM/tree/main/Sept30](https://github.com/jjeongin/intro%E2%80%90to%E2%80%90IM/tree/main/Sept30)). How can I share the link to the specific directory under my repo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your pasted link is encoded:

(Without https://):

> github.com/jjeongin/intro%E2%80%90to%E2%80%90IM/tree/main/Sept30

When I copy it from the browser address bar, it's not encoded:

(Without https://):
github.com/jjeongin/intro-to-IM/tree/main/Sept30

https://github.com/jjeongin/intro-to-IM/tree/main/Sept30